# NPM - How to publish module with project .npmrc settings

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I have a project specific npmrc which I added to the root of my project with the following settings

```
registry=<internal registry>
_auth = <auth token>
email = <email id>
```

I then run

npm publish

but I still get the following error.

```
+ npm publish
npm ERR! need auth auth and email required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

I am not sure why this is happening. My guess is that it isn't reading my project specific npmrc.

Comment: why would I need that? I gave it a shot but still same error. Npm publish command is already there on my machine

Comment: Silly question but are you in the project's root directory that you're trying to publish when running the command?  Have you run 'npm adducer'?

Comment: So this works fine when I have the settings in my home directory that is ~/.npmrc but I need this to work on remote box which is why I was trying to have the .npmrc be a project level